# What kind of skull is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology, bone

[image: side view]

We found this skull on a beach in southwestern Sweden, and are curious as to what kind of animal it was.

[image: bottom view]

[image: frontal view]

Answer (score 26):

It's definitely a bird pelvis ([synsacrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synsacrum)). Based on the size (~30 cm), it came from a very large bird. Unfortunately, comparative images of bird pelves are rare on the internet. Some possibilities (large birds of Sweden possibly found on the coast):

- Great northern loon
- Golden eagle
- Common crane

A loon skeleton (from http://paolov.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/friday-mystery-object-107/) shown below.

[image: Loon skeleton]

Comment: kmm FTW good job

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response - you must be right. We have looked at some alternatives - a cormorant, perhaps, or a goose?

Comment: The top of the synsacrum in the loon isn't flat enough to be a good match. I know that loons have strange pelves, so that was my best guess. Whatever it is, it was a very large bird.

Comment: Crane looks like a decent match, see link, in geese and gulls it is mush shorter and squarer, https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Ventral-view-of-the-synsacrum-fused-with-the-pelvis-A-and-their-scheme-B-in_fig4_259319680