# What type of skull is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology, bone

This skull was found in the mountains/woods of extreme southwestern Virginia (Dickenson County). There is not (to my limited knowledge) any animal native to this area that has this type of skull. Anyone have any idea what it could be? Sorry, no teeth or lower jaw were found. The backbone seems to come directly out from the back of the skull and the nose/beak/front area seems to be flared on the sides.[image]

Comment: It's a bird synsacrum rather than a skull. See http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20089/what-kind-of-skull-is-this Based on size and location, probably a turkey.