# Found Skull(?) in Ontario Canada, help identifying please

Tags: species-identification, zoology

skull?...now maybe thinking its a bird pelvis?...(I don't know thats why I'm here!)on the beach in Northern Ontario Canada, have been wondering what it is. Any ideas? As you can see it is very small, fits in the palm of my friends hand.

Thanks so much!

Kimberley, [image: photo 1]
[image: photo4]

Comment: An old post about Id-ing the [same](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20089/what-kind-of-skull-is-this) bone,Synsacrum .

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a [synsacrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synsacrum), a part of a bird's pelvis. I would say it's from a [cormorant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cormorant), as I have found this comparison of different synsacra online (third from left):

No idea about the exact species, though.

[image]

**Image source:**

https://hiveminer.com/Tags/cormorant,skeleton

Comment: but is the OP's specimen large enough to belong to a cormorant? Please research a little more and update your answer with the expected dimensions/size of a cormorant's synsacrum if possible. Thanks!

Comment: @theforestecologist how does that help? It might be too small for an adult cormorant (even thought theres a wide range of cormorant sizes among the species), but who says it could not be a juvenile?